# Creating an index on a column Vs Creating an index on a clustering column

Tags: cassandra

I would like to understand if there is any performance difference between

[Creating an index on a column](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_eqm_nmd_xj__creating-an-index-on-a-column) Vs [Creating an index on a clustering column](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_eqm_nmd_xj__creating-an-index-on-a-clustering-column)

Answer (score 1):

From the write/read perspective, almost no difference.

The performance of native secondary index will depends greatly on indexed column cardinality rather than index type in your case